# Information diappears when entered into a Multiple lines of text field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, multiline-text-field

Morning

I have a Multiple lines of text field in a SP Online list. When I enter notes in this field initially it shows up with my name and date and time that the information is entered, but after a few minutes it disappears?? Has anyone else had this? How could I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify if your are using the modern interface or classic?

Comment: Whether the content disappears after saving or disappears in the input box after not saving for a period of time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the column where you see this, you have probably turned On "Append changes only settings" disable it

Comment: It's the modern interface. I do have append changes enable because I want to add multiple entries with a date stamp. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Append changes is the right way. Can you check if you see previous comments in Version history.

Comment: Hi @Akshay Raddive No can't see the comments in the version history. Why would the comments be disappearing?

Comment: is someone deleting the version history?